# rabbitmq server doesnt accept remote connections

Tags: ruby, ip, rabbitmq, amqp

I have rabbitmq-server installed on machine A, and client installed on machine B and A.
when i am trying to send msg's using A's client, all good, but when i'm trying to send msg's from B's client, the connection is closed for some reason.

this is the logs:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 15-May-2014::17:09:00 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.456.0> (<machine B ip>:60158 -> <machine A ip>:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 15-May-2014::17:09:00 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.456.0> (<machine B ip>:60158 -> <machine A ip>:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

what could be the reason for that ?

Comment: Which RabbitmMQ version? are you using guest guest as credentials ?

Comment: this is how i use it:
1.9.3-p484 :012 > bunny_cfg = {:host => "<machine A>"}
1.9.3-p484 :013 > conn = Bunny.new bunny_cfg

I am not using any credentials.

version is {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.1.5"}

Comment: I tried to connect from 2 different clients as well (to make sure its not a client side problem), from a python client and from a ruby client. both gave result of connection_closed_abruptly

Comment: Is there some load-balancer, proxy or firewall on the server A ? This error connection_closed_abruptly is a typical error when the connection is closed before the main handshake protocol.

Comment: Ill check the firewall issue, and let you know.

Comment: Is there a way to verify it, i dont have access to the firewall.. ?

Comment: Try to execute a telnet: telnet youserverA 5672 
If the connection is closed immediately could be the firewall

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52792/discussion-between-gas-and-gal)

Comment: I tried to connect with telnet, and it established a connection.

Comment: Hi, Was this resolved? Could you share the solution?

Comment: Hi, we are having the same problem.  Did it resolved for you?  Could you please post a solution?